# Is any subsequence of a sequence of rational numbers dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: analysis, rational-numbers

We know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable so let $\{q_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of all rational numbers.

My Question is:

Is any subsequence $\{q_{n_k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Thanks.

Comment: Obviously not. Consider the subsequence consisting of the $q_n$ such that $q_n>0$.

Comment: "any"?  Or "all"?  "any" is obviously true (take  q_n itself or every other term).  And "all" is obviously false (take the sequence that consist of integers only).

Comment: @fleablood i mean 'all', 'each'

Comment: thanks @DavidC.Ullrich for your answer

Comment: @fleablood thanks for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Any".  Obviously.  The sequence itself is a subsequence.  And if you meant proper sequence just remove one term.   Or take the sequence of those with even denominators, every neighborhood of a real contain a rational with an odd denominator.

"All".  Obviously not.  Take the $q_k$ that are integers.

Comment: +1 I was about to write a comment (as if the existing comments were not enough . . .), but after reading your answer, I think it both answers the question and addresses the ambiguity issues. It's fairly well known (or so I thought) that "any" is often ambiguous and one should mostly avoid its use in formal mathematical statements, and this question gives another example of the kinds of things discussed [In proofs, are “for each” and “for any” synonyms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2696959/in-proofs-are-for-each-and-for-any-synonyms)

Comment: FWIW I take "any" literally.  Is *any* subsequence dense? Well, obviously.  It is it's own subsequence and it is dense...

Comment: The problem is that "any" can sometimes mean "there exists", and "any" can sometimes mean "for all". This is discussed in the links I gave in the question I linked to in my previous comment. See *Be careful with your use of "any"* [here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/words.html) and see *#13* [here](https://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/how-to-write-mathematics/).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  Yes that should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to asking *is any subset of $\mathbb Q$ dense?*.

Some subsets are dense some are not e.g. $\mathbb N$

Comment: thanks @zwim, in effect it's obvious