# Is choosing between universal and existential quantification tricky?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers, logic-translation

I came across some sentences in English that are unclear about quantification: the Discrete Math textbook that I'm using says that

> If you can solve **any** problem we come up with, then you will get A

can be interpreted either as

- If you can solve *every* problem we come up with...

or

- If you can solve *at least one* problem we come up with...

I don't understand why there is more than one interpretation: how can '**any**' can be interpreted as '*at least one*'?

Another example given is that

> I haven't seen **any** of his movies

can be interpreted either as

- I haven't seen *all* of his movies

or

- I haven't seen *at least one* of his movies.

But shouldn't the above statement obviously mean '*all*' rather than '*at least one*'?

Comment: As you imagine, it is an issue of natural Language; see [any](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/any).

Comment: Can you give me any example?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sorry but i actually couldn't find the issue here. I thought **any** means **every** not **atleast one**.

Comment: Ah! @MauroALLEGRANZA. Thanks. It just clicked now. Sorry.

Comment: See the references I give in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2696959/in-proofs-are-for-each-and-for-any-synonyms#comment5568766_2696959).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > If you can solve **any** problem we come up with, then you will get A
>
> how can '**any**' can be interpreted as '*at least one*'?

The consequent "you will get A" is too suggestive; here's a more neutral/ambiguous example, which provides a sharper contrast between the two possible meanings of '**any**':

- If you can solve **any** problem we come up with, then we will hire you;

it is unclear whether the hiring criteria is solving *at least one* problem, or solving *every* problem.

> > I haven't seen **any** of his movies $\quad(\forall m\:\lnot Sm)\tag1$
>
> shouldn't the above statement obviously mean '*all*' rather than '*at least one*'?

- It is not that I have seen **any** of his movies. $\quad(\lnot\exists m\:Sm)\tag2$

Well, although *sentences (1) and (2) are equivalent to each other*, in $(1),$ '**any**' means '*all*', whereas in $(2),$ '**any**' means '*at least one*'.

Read more here: ['Any' versus 'each/every'](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4646789/21813)